# How to define a selection field in flask

Tags: python, flask, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

I want to define a selection field in python, i.e. field that is limited to a set of values. How can I do that in flask framework. I could not find anything on selection fields in the following sources:

[Declaring Models](https://pythonhosted.org/Flask-SQLAlchemy/models.html)
[SQLAlchemy in Flask](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.10/patterns/sqlalchemy/)

I am using sqlalchemy for ORM.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you mean a field in a *form* that has a limited set of options; to do this you can use `WTForms` and its [extensions](http://wtforms.simplecodes.com/docs/0.6.2/ext.html#module-wtforms.ext.sqlalchemy) which allow you to create forms from models.

Once you have done that, you can then limit the choices for a field based on a model condition.

As you haven't posted your model, here is the example give you give you an idea on how this would work:

```
def enabled_categories():
    return Category.query.filter_by(enabled=True)

class BlogPostEdit(Form):
    title    = TextField()
    blog     = QuerySelectField(get_label='title')
    category = QuerySelectField(query_factory=enabled_categories,
                                allow_blank=True)

def edit_blog_post(request, id):
    post = Post.query.get(id)
    form = ArticleEdit(obj=post)
    # Since we didn't provide a query_factory for the 'blog' field, we need
    # to set a dynamic one in the view.
    form.blog.query = Blog.query.filter(Blog.author == request.user) \
                                .order_by(Blog.name)
```